# how to assign values in multiple objects using loop in java

Tags: java, oop

I want to assign different values in multiple objects. Here is my code.

`SaleItem item1 = new SaleItem(); //object created
SaleItem item2 = new SaleItem(); //object created
SaleItem item3 = new SaleItem(); //object created`

//so there are 3 objects created here and I want to assign values to their variables using a loop like this

`for(int i=1,i<4,i++){
item1.setPrice(input.nextInt());}`
// so instead of writing item1 then item2 and so on, I wanted to do this by a loop. Also I do not want to use arrays here

Comment: *Also I do not want to use arrays here* - what?

Comment: Whats **input** here?

Comment: What about a List? List<SaleItem> items = new ArrayList<>()?

Comment: @noMAD probably a Scanner

Comment: input is any integer here

Comment: input is not an issue here I want to assign values in object through loop

Comment: write now I have to assign values to all objects like this
item1.setPrice(input.nextInt());
item1.setPrice(input.nextInt());
item1.setPrice(input.nextInt());

Comment: Why exactly can't you use an array? It's the most straight forward solution here.

Comment: but I want that it can be done via a loop and not by writing item1 then item2 then so on

Comment: `SaleItem itemArr[] = new SaleItem[3]`? Then you get `item[i].setPrice()`

Comment: I know this can be done easily by array but here I have to use different logic then array

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? I can't think of another situation where you would be arbitrarily restricted to not use an array off the top of my head.

Comment: But WHY can't you use an array?

Comment: yes drew you are right it is a assignment

Comment: `List<SaleItem> listItems = Lists.newArrayList();` `listItems.add(new SalesItem().setPrice(input.nextInt()));`

Comment: @noMAD that will only work if SalesItem's setPrice method returns `this`

Comment: @DrewGalbraith with what little information is given, made my assumptions and that's all I could think off :-)

Comment: Do you also have to do it standing on your head, with your tongue out, and both hands tied behind your back?

Answer (score 0):

All those classes can implement a common interface like this:

```
public interface Item {
    public void setPrice(int x);
}
```

then you can use a list like this:

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and finally you can use a for-each loop:

```
for (Item item : list)
    item.setPrice(input.nextInt());
```